# DRF url route did not match for genericview RetrieveUpdateAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-generic-views

I have added the following routes to my Django Rest framework project, the url is matching well and returns the list view for orders and inventories however it does not match for detail view `order/<int:order_no>` and `inventory/<int:pk>`

`localhost:8000/FD/orders/` work but
localhost:8000/FD/order/1/ does not match and returns

```
Using the URLconf defined in FriendsDigital.urls, Django tried these  
URL patterns, in this order:  
 
1. admin/  
2. ^rest-auth/  
3. ^FD/ ^inventories/$ [name='inventory_list']   
4. ^FD/  ^inventory/<int:pk>/ [name='inventory_edit']  
5. ^FD/ ^orders/ [name='orders_list']  
6. ^FD/ ^order/<int:order_no>/ [name='order_update']  

The current path, FD/order/1/, didn't match any of these
```

the same issue is for inventory

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^inventories/$', InventoryList.as_view(), name='inventory_list'),
    url('^inventory/<int:pk>/', InventoryRetrieveUpdate.as_view(), name='inventory_edit'),
    url('^orders/', BusinessOrderList.as_view(), name='orders_list'),
    url('^order/<int:order_no>/',BusinessOrderUpdate.as_view(), name='order_update')
]
```

views.py

```
class InventoryList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset= Inventory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InventorySerializer

class InventoryRetrieveUpdate(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Inventory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InventorySerializer

class BusinessOrderList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = BusinessOrder.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BusinessOrderSerializer

class BusinessOrderUpdate(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = BusinessOrder.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BusinessOrderSerializer
```

Django version - 3.0.7
DjangoRestFramework - 3.11.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRF lookup fields defaults to 'pk', so you have to specify the lookup_fields manually:

```
class BusinessOrderUpdate(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = BusinessOrder.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BusinessOrderSerializer
    lookup_field = 'order_no'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.path) if you want to use the angle bracket notation (`<int:order_no>`) for your urls. The [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#url) function is an alias for `re_path` which uses regular expressions

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('order/<int:order_no>/', BusinessOrderUpdate.as_view(), name='order_update')
]
```